# Google chart is not working with JSP

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

file.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var queryObject="";
            var queryObjectLen="";
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'getdata_wordtree.jsp', //getting JSON encoded data
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
                    queryObjectLen = queryObject.empdetails.length; //empdetails from getdata.jsp
                },
                error : function(xhr, type) {
                    alert('server error occoured');
                }
            });
            google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                //two columns to show chart
                data.addColumn('number', 'day'); //name of string type
                data.addColumn('number', 'sales'); //empid of number type
                data.addColumn('number', 'expenses'); //empid of number type
                for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++)
                {
                    //adding data from JSON retrieved
                    var day = queryObject.empdetails[i].day;
                    var sales = queryObject.empdetails[i].sales;
                    var expenses = queryObject.empdetails[i].expenses;
                    data.addRows([
                        [parseInt(day),parseInt(sales),parseInt(expenses)]
                    ]);
                }
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
                        subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
                    },
                    width: 900,
                    height: 500
                };
                var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="linechart_material"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting JSON response from getdata_wordtree.jsp as follows: `{"empdetails":[{"sales":12,"day":1,"expenses":123}]}` Response is fine! but chart is not displaying on browser. Is there any error in my html file? I am using **Google** Charts.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

- your code uses jQuery, but you didn't include jQuery
- `$.post` runs asynchronously, you must change the workflow to:

  1. load the json via `$.post` in the callback of the JSAPI
  2. draw the chart in the `$.post`-callback
- the object(returned by getdata_wordtree.jsp) has already been parsed by jQuery, parsing it again will result in an error
- when the dataTable contains only a single row, there is nothing that may be displayed, you'll need at least 2 rows

Fixed code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
  $.ajax({
           type     : 'POST',
           url      : 'getdata_wordtree.jsp',
           dataType : 'json',
           success  : function(obj) {

                        var arr = obj.empdetails;
                        if(arr.length<2){
                          alert(arr.length +' row is not enough data, add more');
                          return;
                        }
                        var data    = new google.visualization.DataTable(),
                            options = {
                                        chart: {
                                        title: 'Box Office Earnings in' +  
                                               'First Two Weeks of Opening',
                                        subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
                                        },
                                        width: 900,
                                        height: 500
                                      },
                            chart;

                        data.addColumn('number', 'day');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'sales');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'expenses');
                        $.each(arr,function(){
                          data.addRows([
                                        [this.day,
                                         this.sales,
                                         this.expenses]
                                       ]);
                        });

                        chart = new google.charts
                                 .Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);                        
                      },

            error   : function(xhr, type) {
                        alert('server error occoured');
                      }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="linechart_material"></div>
</body>
</html>
```